# How to get time_zone from other sessions

Tags: oracle

Is there some way to find out the `time_zone` from other sessions defined in session level `(alter session set time_zone = ..)`?

Answer (score 1):

While the V$SES_OPTIMIZER_ENV view lets you see the values of parameters that affect the Cost Based Optimizer across sessions, there does not appear to be any view that lets you see non-performance related settings. Besides the security implications of seeing that information, generally those settings are of interest only to an individual session.